# How to find the closest row in data frame to my sample row in R?

Tags: r

I have data frame *iris* and my set of values *my_row*

```
structure(list(Sepal.Length = 4.65, Sepal.Width = 3.19, Petal.Length = 1.44, 
    Petal.Width = 0.3, Species = structure(1L, .Label = c("setosa", 
    "versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor")), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

> my_row
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1         4.65        3.19         1.44         0.3  setosa

> head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

How to find closest row in *iris* data frame to *my_row*?

Comment: Do you have any threshold for closest

Comment: I have no thresholds

Comment: Do you have any criteria for defining "closest"? Are some columns more important than others? Would it matter if your target row matched another row's numeric columns exactly, but was of a different species?

Comment: All columns have equal importance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may `filter` the rows of 'iris' where the 'Species' matches with the 'Species' from 'my_row', then get the `abs`olute difference between the corresponding numeric columns of both datasets, get the `rowSums` of the difference, and `slice` the row with the minimum value in 'new' column

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
   filter(Species == my_row$Species) %>% 
    mutate(new = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric), 
    ~ abs(.x - my_row[[cur_column()]])))) %>% 
    slice_min(n = 1, order_by = new)
```

-output

```
 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species new
1          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2  setosa 0.2
```